# Kendo scheduler can't update

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

Hi I have this scheduler :

```
var scheduler = $('#scheduler').kendoScheduler({
    date : new date(),
        views: [ 
         "day",
         "week",
         " month"
         ],
    dataSource: {
        transport: {
            read: {
               url: "api/j"
              dataType: "json"
             }
          }
    }
}).getKendoScheduler();
```

When I try to create an event I keep getting the error cannot read property 'data' of undefined. I tried adding a

```
 update: function(e) {  return true; }
```

In the transport but I got the same error. Is there anyway to fix it? And if possible I would like the update to be stored in a Json file too.

*assume I have indicated the schema. Using phone to post this so a bit hard to specify everything. Sorry*

Comment: Possibly it's date reading or parsing error. Please check in network in browser developer's tools if you getting data from this `api/j` url. Also check if you get it in correct format. Basicly array with fields: `id`, `start`, `end` and `title` are required.

Comment: The events show up fine in the scheduler tho. Which means the format should be correct. Just that I can't seem to create new event